# Why my Data is not inserted in Table

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hey I'm new to PHP and codeigniter. I have started with CRUD operation and I'm trying to insert data in my table. Everything seems to work fine but in my table the data is not inserted.
Here is my Model, Controller and View. Please elaborate my mistake in the code. What improvement my code needs.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class stdmain_controller extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
echo "Hello";
}
public function insert_std_record()
{
$this->load->model('stdmain_model');
$this->load->view('std_insert_record');
}
```

Model

```
class Stdmain_model extends CI_Model
{


public function insert_std_record()
{

$data = array('std_name'=>$this->input->post('std_name'),'std_course'=>$this->input->post('std_course'),'std_mob'=>$this->input->post('std_mob') );
$this->db->insert('student_record',$data);

}

}

?>
```

View

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Insert Student Record</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1><center>Add Student Data</center></h1>


<form>
<table border="1"> 
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th><input type="text" name="std_name"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Couse</th>
    <th><input type="text" name="std_course"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Mob No</th>
    <th><input type="text" name="std_mob"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>City</th>
<td colspan="2"><select>
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
</select>
</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit"></center></td>    
</tr>

</table>    
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked MySQL to make sure the SQL command itself is valid syntax?

Comment: Yes it's fine did find any bug in code.

Comment: Your form doesn't have an action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form tag like this

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/stdmain_controller/insert_std_record">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form do not have any action.

Add this in you form opening tag:

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url("stdmain_controller/insert_std_record")?>">
```